# Vue + SSR webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix, server-side-rendering

I am working on a Laravel Project which uses VueJS.
before I was developing only in pre-rendering way. now project almost done.
but I wanted to support SEO, so starting to change to SSR.
I have done V8js PHP extension.
but the problem is in webpack.mix.js

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
let webpack = require('webpack');
mix.setPublicPath('public');

mix
.js('./src/Packages/Front/Resource/assets/js/client.js', 'public/js')
.js('./src/Packages/Front/Resource/assets/js/server.js', 'public/js')
```

in this code, SSR no error.

but if I add .extract(['jQuery' ]) after the mix.js() error will be come up like this.

> V8Js::compileString():1: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

of course, I added in this order the files

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/manifest.js','uyghur') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
 <script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js','uyghur') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="{{ mix('/js/client.js','uyghur') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

does anyone know what exactly this error means?

it is taking lots of my time. already takes 3 days.
I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar doing SSR with Laravel and Vue; but I want to suggest not to use extract since you're doing SSR.  Though, your issue may just be figuring out how to have the V8 load all Javascript before compiling it.  Let me provide  some reasoning and alternative that may help with your troubleshooting:

1. The reason why you need the output to be in that particular order because `webpackJsonp` is mix build into `manifest.js`.  You should be able to find that function in there.  Since you didn't provide any v8 code, let me try to guess it here:

```js
$manifestSrc = File::get(public_path('js/manifest.js'));
$vendorSrc   = File::get(public_path('js/vendor.js'));
$appSrc      = File::get(public_path('js/entry-server.js'));

$allSrc = $manifestSrc . $vendorSrc . $appSrc;

$v8->executeString($allSrc);
```

2. With `jQuery`, it's probably easier to define it as external, like so:

```php
mix.webpackConfig({
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
  }
 // other settings
})
```

Then you don't need to worry about loading both `manifest.js` and `vendor.js` on the V8 side.

Note, if you're using jQuery for rendering on the server, then you must also append it on the server per the example above.  This is where I'm not up-to-date on.  I'm not sure what the latest on V8js and jQuery but they don't historically play well together.  People tends to use NodeJS instead of V8js for jQuery usage on the server-side.